# Trying to call function using a void pointer inside a variable type

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, pic, xc8

In the firmware that I am writing, I created a type of variable. Similar to what is below:

```
    struct SitemMenu {
      unsigned int id;
      char * text;
      void * submenu
    }
    typedef struct SitemMenu TitemMenu;
```

Be any function:

```
    void functionX () {
      ...
    }
```

If I create this variable:

```
    TitemMenu itemWhatever;
```

and do:

```
    itemWhatever.submenu = &function (X);
```

Can I call functionX doing:

```
    (*itemWhatever.submenu)();
```

I did something similar to this and the compiler give this answer:

```
    error: (183) function or function pointer required
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can, but not quite the way you've written it.
A function pointer is not declared in quite the same way as a 'normal' pointer.
What you need is:

```
struct SitemMenu {
  unsigned int id;
  char * text;
  void (* submenu)(void); // this is a function pointer, as opposed to the 'normal' pointer above
};

typedef struct SitemMenu TitemMenu;
TitemMenu itemWhatever;
```

then, if you have some function declared with the same parameters and return type, like:
`void functionX(void)`, then you can do:

```
itemWhatever.submenu = functionX;
itemWhatever.submenu();
```